# what is the best practice to change the range of a partitioned table that already exists in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

First off, i am kinda new to programming...lets assume I have created 6 filegroup/file(null, file with data, file with data, file with data, file with data, null) to partition a table in the beginning.And Range is 5,10,15+ million. And by time users have filled this table and i realized that it reached 23 million rows. And of course i wanna limit each filegroup file with 5 million rows. So i wanted to change partition structure of partitioned table and reorganize this partitioned table i mean adding new filegroups and files as 5,10,15,20,25,30+ million. How should i do that? or should i follow a completely different solution or smth else? Thank you...

Comment: Whats the purpose of the table? What type of data are there? What queries run against it?

Comment: lets assume it is a relational(with Role table) User table, that keeps user data like name, emails etc...

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the partition function, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186307.aspx

Note that splitting the table where there is existing data is going to take a while (depending on how much data) and will lock teh table whilst it runs. Generally you want to create partitions ahead of time.

Comment: in this article i quoted 2 part. 1) "...Avoid splitting or merging populated partitions..." and 2)"...Create a new partitioned table with the desired partition function, and then insert the data from the old table into the new table by using an INSERT INTO SELECT FROM statement...". So imho i think it is best to create new partitioned table and insert the whole data to this new partitioned table. imho this is the best practice, but if there would be a quicker way it would be nice of course.